# How to center two Texts in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the next widget:

```
class PoinstsDisplayState extends State<PoinstsDisplay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: new Text(
        '5000 Pts',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontFamily: 'Karla'
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

That looks like this:

[image]

That have the perfect position, now I want to style the number 5000 and the 'Pts' text separately but I have not managed to make it work (center two text like the image), I am try with a Row, more Containers, the Center Class etc, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use some combination of `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`, and placing some padding or an empty `Container` with a set width between the two text widgets for the space.

```
class PointsDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
            '5000',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0,
              fontFamily: 'Karla'
            ),
          ),
          Container(width: 5.0,height: 0,),
          Text(
            'Pts',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontFamily: 'Times'
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

This is a perfect use of the [rich text constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.rich.html) with a couple of [`TextSpan`s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html).

Taking from the 2nd sample in the [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html), try:

```dart
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: '5000 ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      TextSpan(text: 'pts', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
    ],
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20.0,
    fontFamily: 'Karla'
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have a `WidgetSpan` as a **children** of `TextSpan`, you can use:

```
WidgetSpan(
     child: Icon(Icons.access_time),
     alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RichText`: [Video](https://youtu.be/rykDVh-QFfw) | [Document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

```
RichText(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```